# Effective way to invoke generic interface method in runtime

Tags: c#, performance, generics, reflection, event-handling

I'm working on the some kind of EventSourcing architecture and have 2 main concepts in my app - `events` and `handlers`.

Events example:

```
class NewRecordCreated: EventMessage {...}
```

And there some handlers looks like:

```
class WriteDBHandler: IEventHandler<NewRecordCreated>, IEventHandler<RecordUpdated> { 
    public void Handle(NewRecordCreated eventMessage) {...}
    public void Handle(RecordUpdated eventMessage) {...} 
}
```

And also I have custom implementation of queue protocol which dispatch events to proper handlers. So basically on app startup I parse assembly and create mapping between event and handlers based on types.

So when I actually dispatching events to handlers I based on event type getting chain of handler's types - something like `var handlerChain = [typeof(WriteDbHandler), typeof(LogHandler), typeof(ReadModelUpdateHandler)]` and for each of those handlers I need to invoke it's instance, then cast it to proper interface (`IEventHandler<>`) and than invoke `Handle` method.

But I can't cast to generic interface, since it's not possible. I think about options of implementing non generic version of interface, but it's seems quite unpleasant for me to add extra method implementation each time, especially if there no any real reasons for it.

I think about dynamic invocation or reflection, but both of this variants seems have performance issues. Maybe you could advice me some suitable alternatives?

Comment: You can use run-time code generation, it's pretty easy with [`LambdaExpression.Compile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx)

Comment: What does the `IEventHandler<T>` interface look like? Does it only have the one `void Handle(EventMessage)` method? Does it use the generic type parameter for anything in the interface itself, or is that just for identifying what kind of handler a class is?

Comment: question body updated

Comment: Can you describe the handler lifetime? When do they instantiated.. during dispatch... during application start up? When do they go out of scope?

Comment: At the current moment base idea - 1 handler per one event. So for next event - new instance should be created. Maybe at later time if there will be some heavy handlers - some kind of pool will be introduced, but I don't want to over-complicate this for now.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski compiled expressions looks like interesting way to go. However every example I saw assume that type defined before compilation which isn't fit well for runtime type definition. Of course it's possible to compile expression every time for new requested type - but this seems not effective for me. Could you clarify your vision with small example?

Comment: @Ph0en1x the idea is to cache the compiled expressions, recompiling them each time would be slower than using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

### Using reflection

Rather than trying to cast to `IEventHandler<>`, you can instead use reflection to get a reference to the method you need to invoke. The code below is a good example. It simplifies the "queue protocol" for sake of brevity, but it should sufficiently illustrate the reflection that you need to do.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Dictionary<Type, List<Type>> handlerTypesByMessageType = new Dictionary<Type, List<Type>>();

        // find all types in the assembly that implement IEventHandler<T>
        // for some value(s) of T
        foreach (var t in a.GetTypes())
        {
            foreach (var iface in t.GetInterfaces())
            {
                if (iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventHandler<>))
                {
                    var messageType = iface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    if (!handlerTypesByMessageType.ContainsKey(messageType))
                        handlerTypesByMessageType[messageType] = new List<Type>();
                    handlerTypesByMessageType[messageType].Add(t);
                }
            }
        }

        // get list of events
        var messages = new List<EventMessage> {
            new NewRecordCreated("one"),
            new RecordUpdated("two"),
            new RecordUpdated("three"),
            new NewRecordCreated("four"),
            new RecordUpdated("five"),
        };

        // process all events
        foreach (var msg in messages)
        {
            var messageType = msg.GetType();
            if (!handlerTypesByMessageType.ContainsKey(messageType))
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("No handlers for that type");
            }

            if (handlerTypesByMessageType[messageType].Count < 1)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("No handlers for that type");
            }

            // look up the handlers for the message type
            foreach (var handlerType in handlerTypesByMessageType[messageType])
            {
                var handler = Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType);
                // look up desired method by name and parameter type
                var handlerMethod = handlerType.GetMethod("Handle", new Type[] { messageType });
                handlerMethod.Invoke(handler, new object[]{msg});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled this and ran it on my machine and got what I believe are the correct results.

### Using run-time code generation

If reflection is not fast enough for your purposes, you can compile code on-the-fly for each input message type and execute that.
The `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace has facilities for doing just that.
You can define a dynamic method (not to be confused with the `dynamic` keyword, which is something else), and emit a sequence if IL opcodes that will run each handler in the list in sequence.

```
public static Dictionary<Type, Action<EventMessage>> GenerateHandlerDelegatesFromTypeLists(Dictionary<Type, List<Type>> handlerTypesByMessageType)
{
    var handlersByMessageType = new Dictionary<Type, Action<EventMessage>>();
    foreach (var messageType in handlerTypesByMessageType.Keys)
    {
        var handlerTypeList = handlerTypesByMessageType[messageType];

        if (handlerTypeList.Count < 1)
            throw new NotImplementedException("No handlers for that type");

        var method =
            new DynamicMethod(
                "handler_" + messageType.Name,
                null,
                new [] { typeof(EventMessage) });
        var gen = method.GetILGenerator();
        foreach (var handlerType in handlerTypeList)
        {
            var handlerCtor = handlerType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
            var handlerMethod =
                handlerType.GetMethod("Handle", new Type[] { messageType });

            // create an object of the handler type
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, handlerCtor);
            // load the EventMessage passed as an argument
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            // call the handler object's Handle method
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, handlerMethod);
        }

        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var del = (Action<EventMessage>)method.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Action<EventMessage>));

        handlersByMessageType[messageType] = del;
    }
}
```

Then, instead of invoking the handlers with `handlerMethod.Invoke(handler, new object[]{msg})`, you just call the delegate like any other, with `handlersByMessageType[messageType](msg)`.

Full code listing [here](https://gist.github.com/izrik/fcc04291972d83ee7b4c3f84b6ed73cc).

The actual code generation is done in the `GenerateHandlerDelegatesFromTypeLists` method.
It instantiates a new `DynamicMethod`, gets its associated `ILGenerator`, and then emits opcodes for each handler in turn.
For each handler type, it will instantiate a new object of that handler type, load the event message onto the stack, and then execute the `Handle` method for that message type on the handler object.
This is of course assuming that the handler types all have zero-parameter constructors.
If you need to pass arguments to the constructors, though, you'll have to modify it considerably.

There are other ways to speed this up even more.
If you relax the requirement to create a new handler object with every message, then you could just create the objects while generating the code, and load them.
In that case, replace `gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, handlerCtor)` with `gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj, handlerObjectsByType[handlerType])`.
That gives you two benefits:
  1. you're avoiding an allocation on every message
  2. you can instantiate the objects any way you want when you populate the `handlerObjectsByType` dictionary. You can even use constructors with parameters or factory methods.

Comment: `var handlerMethod = handlerType.GetMethod("Handle", new Type[] { messageType });`
                `handlerMethod.Invoke(handler, new object[]{msg});` Yes, this what I thought when talking about reflection, but I think this is one of the less effective way of doing invocation as far as I know. Probably casting handler instance to dynamic with `((dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType)).Handle(event)` will be more effective, but still around 12 times slower than direct virtual method call.

Comment: @Ph0en1x I'm pretty sure there's no way to do a virtual method call from a `Type` object. Normally, the compiler does method resolution using type information available only at compile-time.

Comment: Yes, sure. But I think there is potentially more option like expression.compile or CIL generation exists, but I don't really advanced in this topics, so looking for opinions.

Comment: @Ph0en1x Ah, yes. I understand now. I've used the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace in the past. Tomorrow I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: @Ph0en1x How's that?

Comment: I implemented simple benchmark to play with it. And what I found is just `handlerType.GetMethod("Handle", new Type[] { messageType });` call takes comparable time to dynamic instantiation and calling together (around 80 ns on my machine, based on BecnmarkDotNet lib results). So this, i think, will not be faser since there is quite a lot of other code as well. But anyway, thanks a lot for your time.